# Why is there no variation caused by this swept parameter?

Tags: simulation, qucs

I quite like Qucs now that I more or less have the hang of it. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to get a parametric sweep working.

I'm running an AC simulation on this circuit:

[image: schematic]

For now I'm not asking on how to improve or fix this circuit; solely on how to fix parametric sweep simulation.

The output of the simulation is shown in this table:

[image: simulation table]

The gain is not being affected by the inductor sweep when it most certainly should be. How do I fix the sweep?

Comment: You need to set the inductance of one of your inductors to have the value `Lant`. (And probably make a variable definition so the model will still be valid when you aren't running the sweep)

Comment: Meaning, you have an inductor with designator Lant, but its inductance is 10.042 uH. You probably should change its inductance to be `Lant` instead.

Comment: Caveat: I don't use Qucs, but I do use ADS, which is the commercial tool that Qucs seems to be trying to copy.

Comment: @ThePhoton OK. I'm unable to see where I make a variable definition?

Comment: In ADS, there's a "variable definition" object you add to the schematic, similar to the equation object in your design where you define `G`.

Comment: @ThePhoton Qucs might not have that feature. Regardless, your suggestion worked. If you submit it as an answer I'll accept it- thanks.

Comment: It's probably better if you make an answer, showing how to actually do it in Qucs.

Answer (score 0):

As @ThePhoton indicated, the proper way to use a parametric variable is to write a variable name in the Parameter Sweep `param` and to write the same variable name instead of a constant value in the component field that you want to sweep; i.e.:

[image: sweep]

[image: capacitor]